# Reducing room on recordings

Tags: recording, foley, reverb, reverberant

Hey

Looking for any bright ideas to help me... Im a sound editor recording some feet in my lounge  for a feature - I have a creaky old hollow wood floor which is absolutely perfect for deck of a ship, better than any foley studio surfaces. Problem Im having is reducing room reflections on recording.
Save for professionally treating my lounge, which aint gonna happen! Any suggestions?

I have tried recording with a huge quilt over me, and mic inside, and still sounded too roomy to be honest, plus difficulty in reducing movement noise.
Im using a 416 into a H4, though have access to various other mics & lapel mics.

Someone suggested attaching a lapel mic to my ankle, which I may try - but any other suggestion be appreciated..
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Drop packing blankets across the whole floor and only lay bare what you want to record on.

Then, put packing blankets over mic stands and put those in a circle all the way around you.

If that STILL doesn't work, I'd search for another room that has a lot of upholstery and couches and chairs with cushions etc.

Or just get 5 to 10 people to come in and stand in the room with you (if this is feasible). This always deadens a room and reflection by about 30% I've found when recording multi-cast audiobooks. Make sure they are quiet!

Answer (score 2):

Try bringing some large / thick pillows rather close to what you are recording, forming a boundary between your sound and the rest of the room. Aim the mic at the sound, facing towards the pillows. Usually deadens fairly well.

Also, make sure your mic is as close to the source as you can get it, while maintaining a decent sonic quality.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, record it from below.  Then again, perhaps the boomyness below it is actually the problem.

Professional studios have those movable sound-absorbing panels, and you can build something similar with some 2x6s, rockwool, and canvas to seal them up.  Also, moving blankets can work as sound blankets in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Great ideas, thanks! Though dont have access below really. I just discovered 'de verb' plugin, working wonders in making recordings usable, de reverbing the recordings. Anyone else use this?

Comment: Deverb is popular but is not first line of defence.. 

Answer (score 1):

Check this plug-in out:

[SPL De-Verb](http://spl.info/software/microplugs/de-verb.html)

It gets rid of the reverb tail pretty well, however, it does keep some early reflections.

Sounds great though, and is probably more than worth a try!

Cheers

Comment: @Fred, is it just a well calibrated gate filter?

Comment: @Miles I don't think it's quite a gate. More of a compressor. It uses their Transient Designer protocol so it kind of shapes the envelope of the sound. It works pretty well though! 

Answer (score 0):

I found a 12 pack of Rock Wool on crags list for 100.00 US yesterday.... The room sound is probably reflecting from the walls.... I would suggest hanging blankets on the walls rather than covering the floor... A big Sofa or Chair in the room will help with Bass reflection... But you need to cover the walls to reduce reflections in the higher frequency....

Answer (score 0):

Using a 416 for foley often works well in a treated foley studio, but is not a good choice in other interior situations. The coloration from the tube and the remaining rear lobe pickup sounds awful. 
I'd suggest using another low noise mic, not a shotgun.

Comment: yes, that kind of room is not good for a shot gun. your better off using a sm58 close to your feet, its not an ideal mic for foley by any means BUT if your looking for alternatives rather then treating the room, it wont pick up very many reflections. You can hang it by the xlr and let it dangle as you walk with it. It doesnt have to be a 58, just any small dynamic should work.